# How can I create ~/.vim/colors directory?

Tags: vim, colors, directory

I try to apply color scheme to Mac vim.

```
cd vim-color-solarized/colors
```

and

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
```

but it doesn't work with a 'Not a directory'

Also, I tried

```
mv solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
```

but 'Not a directory' again.

What should I do to move **solarized.vim** to **~/.vim/colors/** ?

Comment: Do you have a solarized.vim file/dir from where you are doing mv solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/ ?

Comment: Yeap. I download solarized from website and I check solarized.vim exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have `.vim` as a file.

```
mv ~/.vim ~/.vim.bak
mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors
```

Comment: Wow it works!! Actually I tried vi ~/.vim/colors before mkdir.. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: And you can move the file `~/.vim` to `~/.vim/init.vim`.